# Edit HTML with returned jQuery html() content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, string

I want to edit some HTML I get from a var I saved. like:

```
var testhtml = $('.agenda-rename').html();
console.log($('input',testhtml).attr('name'));
```

Also tried

```
console.log($(testhtml).find('input').attr('name'));
```

But i get `undefined`? I figured it'd work like an $.ajax, $.get, $.post? How else can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.html()`, you're only getting the content, not the `.agenda-rename`. So if the `input` is a direct child of `.agenda-rename`, then `.find()` won't be able to find it.

Probably better just to do without the `.html()` call:

```
var testhtml = $('.agenda-rename').clone();  // or .clone(true)
console.log($('input',testhtml).attr('name'));
```

Now you have the `.agenda-rename` element(s) and you'll be able to search for elements nested inside it/them.

---

**EDIT:** Based on comment, OP doesn't want to modify the original. As such, `.clone()` can be used. Answer above has been edited to reflect change.

If events are attached that should be retained, then you use `.clone(true)`.

---

**EDIT:** The reason `$('input',testhtml)` and `$(testhtml).find('input')` give the same result is that they are actually the same thing.

jQuery converts the first version into the second behind the scenes. As such it is technically a little more efficient to use the second than the first.

Here's the code where jQuery makes the switch (after running a bunch of other tests to determine what it was passed).

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L150

Comment: Wont this modify $('.agenda-rename') though? I want to keep that is and not modify it. Im trying to create inline templates basically that i clone, modify, then display in this modal type interface.

Comment: @Oscar - If you don't want to modify it, you would need to `.clone()` it. If there are events attached that you want to retain, then call `.clone(true)`. I'll update.

Comment: @Oscar - If you did it the way you had it, you could use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`. The `.filter()` method filters through elements at the top level. But if there were any inputs nested deeper, it would not get those. Better to `.clone()` your element so you have what you expect.

Comment: 'Nother quick question though, so, var testhtml = $('.agenda-rename').clone(); testhtml = $('input',testhtml).val('test'); just returns the input with the new val(), is there a way to simply modify the html while keeping it in the var?

Comment: @Oscar - With your code, you are overwriting the element stored in `testhtml` and losing the reference to the original clone. Just treat `testhtml` like it was a typical element that you selected from the DOM. `testhtml = $('.agenda-rename').clone(); $('input',testhtml).val('test');`  Now `testhtml` still references the clone of the `.agenda-rename` that you created, but the value of the `input` has been updated. If you do `console.log(testhtml)` you should see the updated HTML with the new value.

Comment: ...If you want a separate reference to the `<input>` then use a different variable name. `var myInput = $('input',testhtml).val('test');` Now `myInput` refers to the `<input>` element you found in the clone, and `testhtml` still refers to the original clone (with that updated `<input>`).